# Order property on dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rational-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be dedekind cuts, we say that $a \prec b$,(thats $a \subsetneq b$) and
considering  $0^* \prec c$( Thats mean  $\exists p\in c$, $p>0$)

I want to prove that:

$ca \prec cb$

I am starting some notes on dedekind cuts and this is a proposed exercise, but sadly I have not been able to solve it. Searching on the internet I have not found this property, so I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: You could of course include the exercise and wait for the students to solve it for you ;)

Comment: It appears you have the correct idea of order relations on Dedekind cuts. You should first prove that $a\prec b$ iff $a-b\prec 0^{*}$ and then prove that if $0^{*}\prec a, 0^{*}\prec b$ then $0^{*}\prec ab$.

Comment: Please give it  try and show yiur effort here. And if you get stuck at some point people here will gladly offer you any help you need. But don't waste the opportunity for trying yourself.

Comment: for the first part I have already proven that $a+(-a)=0^*$ so $a \prec b$ iff $a-b \prec 0^*$ its clear. for the second one i think thats $0^*  \subsetneq ab$ basically by definition of product $ab:=\{ r\leq 0$ or $ r<pq\}$ where $p,q>0$ and $p \in a, q \in b$

Comment: Then we are done! $0^{*} \prec b-a$ due to given constraint and $0^{*}<c$ also given therefore $0^{*}<c(b-a)=cb-ca$ and this implies $ca<cb$.